# Due to null value of $(DefaultDataPath) Could not publish my DBProject to SQL Server 2017 on linux based Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

I am working on VS2017 SSDT with my DBProject while multiple FileGroups. Locally on Windows based SQL Server Instance this DBProject is deployed without any problem but when I deploy this Multi FileGroup based DBProject to my SQl Server 2017 on docker instance during deployment the following error occurs and deployment gets terminated.

> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name
>   'ActiveBiz.Core1_ArchTransactionDataFile_1.ndf' may be incorrect.
>   Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   (43,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

In google search I found that `$(DefaultDataPath)` not resolving due to this this filename without any path appears. Also find that We cannot set the value for `$(DefaultDataPath)` via code inside Deployment Script. So Can anyone tell me how to resolve this Issue?

Regards,

Nilkanth S. Desai

Comment: By the time I recd any answer I tried running Add File Script Manually from SSMA and it runs successfully & it shows that there were no issues related to permission on OS. But still unable to publish from VS2017 to This Docker machine same Issue.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue now ... more than 2 years after your initial post.  Have you any more information that could help solve it?